# Let $A_1, A_2,\dots$ be a sequence of disjoint, finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. How can $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ be either finite or infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_n$ be finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are not $\emptyset$, and $\forall i,j, i\not = j$, $A_i, A_j$ are disjoint, then must 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \mathbb{N}$$
and thus be (countably) infinite?

So basically I am looking for an example of $A_1,A_2,\dots$ such that
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$
is finite.

Or, is the only way for the infinite union to be finite for $A_i =A_j = \emptyset$?

Thanks.

Edit: A comment has answered how $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \not = \mathbb{N}$ is possible. I am not sure if it must be infinite, though, when $A_n \not = \emptyset$

Comment: What if $A_i=\emptyset$?

Comment: Well, you should specify that the $A_i$ are non-empty (if that's what you want).  Also:  there's no reason why the union should be all of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: As for why $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ does not have to be $\Bbb N$ when each are nonempty, consider the example where $A_i = \{3i\}$ for each $i$.  Then $\bigcup A_i$ only contains multiples of three, and in particular does not have numbers like $1,2,4,5,7,8,\dots$.

Comment: @i707107 I'll specify that, thanks. I overlooked the fact that $\emptyset$ is disjoint with itself

Comment: If the sets are disjoint and non-empty  $|\cup_{i=n}^n A_i| = \sum |A_i| \ge \sum 1 = n+ 1$.  So $|\cup_{i+n}^{\infty}A_i|$ must be larger than any finite number.  So it is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be countable (i.e. in bijection with $\Bbb N$), but not necessarily $=\Bbb N$.

Let $f: \Bbb N \to \bigcup_n A_n$ be given by $f(n) = \min A_n$. It is clear that $f$ is injective, so $\bigcup_n A_n$ is at least as large as $\Bbb N$. Now since the countable union of finite sets is at most countable, it follows that $\cup_n A_n$ is countable.

As suggested in the comments, the sequence $(A_n)$ where $A_n := \{3n\}$ satisfies the requirement, yet the union is not $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

If the $A_i$ are nonempty and disjoint, each must contain a distinct integer. Therefore any finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ can only contain a finite number of the $A_i$, since $\bigcup_{i=0}^N A_i$ contains at least $N$ distinct integers.

In conclusion, yes, the union must be infinite under these conditions, but as pointed out in the comments, it need not be all of $\mathbb{N}$.